# Is it possible to write a single Pcollection at different Output sinks without using side inputs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a specific use case for writing my pipeline data. I wanted to make a single Pub/Sub Subscription and wanted to read those from that single source and write the Pcollection at multiple sinks without making another Pub/Sub subscription for it. I've been wanting to make a Pipeline such that I've multiple pipelines in a single dataflow working in parallel and write the same pipeline data, firstly in Google Cloud Storage and Secondly at Bigquery by just using a single subscription.
Code or references for the same would be helpful and bring light to the direction I'm working in.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to do multi sinks in your `Beam` job to meet your need.

In `Beam` you can build a `PCollection` and then sink this `PCollection` to multiple places :

Example with Beam `Python` :

```py
result_pcollection = (inputs | 'Read from pub sub' >> ReadFromPubSub(
                    subscription=subscription_path) 
        | 'Map 1' >> beam.Map(your_map1) 
        | 'Map 2' >> beam.Map(your_map2)
      )

# Sink to Bigquery
(result_pcollection | 'Map 3' >> beam.Map(apply_transform_logic_bq)
                    | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                    project=project_id,
                    dataset=dataset,
                    table=table,
                    method='YOUR_WRITE_METHOD',
                  write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
)

# Sink to GCS
(result_pcollection | 'Map 4' >> beam.Map(apply_transform_logic_gcs)
                    | 'Windowing logic' >> WindowInto(FixedWindows(10*60))
                    |  fileio.WriteToFiles(path=known_args.output)
)
```

To be able to write a streaming flow to `GCS`, you need applying windowing and generate a file per window.

Comment: How will mapping the input Pcollection here help, can I also sink them directly to their sources and you're sinking Map1 to both GCS aswell as Bigquery, is that a typo or it is how it is? Sorry am a newbie in apache beam

Comment: I shown a code snippet with map operations, only for the example. I edited for the map 1, and yes you can directly sink the input PCollection to Bigquery if your current Dict matches the schema of Bigquery table. For GCS your need to apply a windowing on the pcollection.

Comment: Mille fois merci!!

Comment: De rien ;) with pleasure

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is definitely possible. In Java, you can do something like this:

```java
PCollection<PubsubMessage> messages = p.apply(PubsubIO.read()...);

// Write messages to GCS
messages.apply(TextIO.write()...);

// Write messages to BQ
messages.apply(BigQueryIO.write()...);
```

The messages will only be consumed once from pubsub. You can define multiple  branches of your pipeline that all read from the same `PCollection`.

The downside here is really around error handling. If your BigQuery sink has errors that cause the pipeline to fail, it will be taking down your GCS output as well. It's harder to reason about these failure scenarios when you have multiple sinks in one pipeline.

You mention "firstly in Google Cloud Storage and Secondly at Bigquery"; if the order of writes is important (you don't want data showing up in BQ if it isn't also in GCS), that's significantly more difficult to express, and you'd likely be better off creating a second pipeline that reads from the GCS output of the first pipeline and writes to BQ.